# DevOps pipeline running python script error on import azureml.core

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to run a Python script in a DevOps pipeline upon check in. A basic 'hellow world' script works, but when I import azureml.core, it errors out with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml'.

That makes sense, since I don't know how it was going to find azureml.core. My question is: how do I get the Python script to find the module? Do I need to check it in as part of my code base in DevOps? Or is there some way to reference it via a hyperlink?

Here is my YML file:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filepath'
    scriptPath: test.py
```

And here is my python script:

```
print('hello world')

import azureml.core
from azureml.core import Workspace

# Load the workspace from the saved config file
ws = Workspace.from_config()
print('Ready to use Azure ML {} to work with {}'.format(azureml.core.VERSION, ws.name))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the lost package into your python, the default python does not have that. Please use the below yml:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.8'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 3.8

- script: python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
  displayName: 'upgrade pip'

- script: python3 -m pip install azureml.core
  displayName: 'Install azureml.core'



- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs: 
    scriptSource: 'filepath'
    scriptPath: test.py
```

Comment: If using a Windows image, use "py" instead of "python3"